# hosting a processing.js project on github pages?

Tags: processing, commit, github-pages, processing.js

Is it possible to host a processing.js file on github pages?  I tried committing a .pde file to my repository and I got the message:

```
$ git commit hello_web.pde "first pde"
error: pathspec 'first pde' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

According to this [guide](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html), the pde code should be compiled into pure javascript.  I can understand why git would not allow me to commit a file type it doesn't recognize, but is there a way to compile the pde into js and simply commit the outputted file?  Has anyone done this or something similar to get processingjs to work on github pages?

Comment: your command syntax is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with Processing. You're having an issue with git.

It looks like you want this instead:

```
git commit hello_web.pde -m "first pde"
```

The **-m** bit allows you to provide a **m**essage. Without it, git is looking for a file named "first pde", which is why you're getting the error.

Consult the [git reference](http://gitref.org/basic/) for questions like these.